# System.Web.UI.WebControls.Style renders obsolete HTML5

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I'm using the w3.org HTML validator to test the HTML5 for http://nflpowerrank.com, and I get the following validation error:

*The cellspacing attribute on the table element is obsolete. Use CSS instead.*

It appears that cellspacing="0", which is rendered by the system.web.ui.webcontrol.style class, is rendering the obsolete version of cellspacing="0" instead of the .css.

I found another related bug on the microsoft site: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/747004/system-web-ui-webcontrols-style-renders-obsolete-html5

Does anyone know if Microsoft has fixed this issue? Is there a way not render the cell spacing tag? Or should I use a different style grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an easier approach, I can simply set the cellspacing attribute to cellspacing="-1" in the gridview in design mode. This bypassed the error and my page validated as HTML5

Answer (score 2):

You could always use a control adapter to render the output as you like.

Microsoft has come up with [Control Adapters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163543.aspx) for such purposes.

> Instead of creating alternate renderings of controls for specific
>   devices, this toolkit defines a number of control adapters that change
>   the default table-based renderings of several controls (like Menu,
>   TreeView, and FormView) to eschew tables completely and render using
>   , , and  elements with associated styles defined in CSS
>   stylesheets (a common requirement for site designs today).

An implementation of [CSS friendly control adapters](http://www.asp.net/cssadapters/) is already available.